# Python - create dynamic nested dictionary from list of dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, recursive-datastructures

Below is sample list data, I want to convert it into a dynamic dictionary.

```
result = [
    {
        "standard": "119",
        "score": "0",
        "type": "assignment",
        "student": "4"
    },
    {
        "standard": "119",
        "score": "0",
        "type": "assignment",
        "student": "5"
    },
    {
        "standard": "118",
        "score": "0",
        "type": "assessment",
        "student": "4"
    }
]
```

I want to create one function conv_to_nested_dict(*args,data), which convertes all list of key to dictonary dynamically.

For example : conv_to_nested_dict(['standard','student'],result) should give op :

```
{
    "118": {
        "4": [{
            "score": "0",
            "type": "assessment"
        }]
    },
    "119": {
        "4": [{
            "score": "0",
            "type": "assignment"
        }],
        "5": [{
            "score": "0",
            "type": "assignment"
        }]
    }

}
```

conv_to_nested_dict(['standard','type'],result)

```
{
    "118": {
        "assessment": [{
            "score": 0,
            "student": "4"
        }]
    },
    "119": {
        "assignment": [{
            "score": 0,
            "student": "4"
        },{
            "score": 0,
            "student": "5"
        }]
    }

}
```

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: @wroniasty I am stuck while thinking logics, I tried with a couple of approaches like using group by in Python and filters. I want to make it generic and dynamic so asked for help. The main problem I am facing is keys are dynamic in output dictionary.

Comment: There seems to be an error in the desired output structure. You have a list that is not closed. Please clean it up and clarify the question

Comment: @XeroSmith I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a general idea.

```
def conf_to_nested_dict(keys, result):
    R = {}
    for record in result: 
        node = R
        for key in keys[:-1]:
            kv = record[key]
            next_node = node.get(kv, {})
            node[kv] = next_node
            node = next_node
        last_node = node.get(record[keys[-1]], [])
        last_node.append(record)
        node[record[keys[-1]]] = last_node


    return R

#R is your structure
```

`result` is your source array, `keys` are the keys by which you want to group results. Iterate over results, for each record - create a tree structure based on key values ( record[key] ). For the last key - create a list and append the record to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, This worked perfectly fine. You saved my day, thanks. :)